# How to pass a value from view to a controller in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been developed a controller who builds a table from data got them from backend through $http.get.

I would like to know how to pass a value to this controller from the view which it tells which URL has to use to get the data that he is going to use to build the table.

How can I do that?

I have tried to do this but it doesn't work.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller = "paginatorController" ng-init = "initilize(1)">
   .....
   .....
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
demo.factory("ServiceURL", [function() {
  return {
    url: [
        "/privado/usuario/getcoduser",  
        "/privado/usuario/list"         
    ] 
  };
}]);

demo.controller( "demoCtrl", ["$http", "$scope", "ServiceURL", function($http, $scope, ServiceURL) {

    this.initialize = function( type) {
        self.type = type;
        //Inside of this function self.type is correctly initialized
    }

   //But here, self.type is undefined, and gives me an error!!!
   $http.get(ServiceURL.url[self.type])
        .success(function(response){
            //More code
         }      
    }).error(function(response){
        //More code
    });

}]);
```

If what I'm trying to do is not possible, is there any other way to do what I want?

**I have found a solution:**

I have created an external function where I put all my controller code which builds the table, and then, in the controller I have jut a call to this function passing the correct params and it works fine.

**HTML:**

```
 <div ng-controller = "demoCtrl1">
   .....
   .....
 </div>

 <div ng-controller = "demoCtrl2">
   .....
   .....
 </div>

 <div ng-controller = "demoCtrl3">
   .....
   .....
 </div>
```

**JS:**

```
function buildTable($http, $scope, ServiceURL, indexURL){

   $http.get(ServiceURL.url[indexURL])
        .success(function(response){
            //More code
         }      
    }).error(function(response){
        //More code
    });
}

demo.controller( "demoCtrl1", ["$http", "$scope", "ServiceURL", function($http, $scope, ServiceURL) {

    buildTable($http, $scope, ServiceURL.url[1]);

}]);

demo.controller( "demoCtrl2", ["$http", "$scope", "ServiceURL", function($http, $scope, ServiceURL) {

    buildTable($http, $scope, ServiceURL.url[2]);

}]);

demo.controller( "demoCtrl3", ["$http", "$scope", "ServiceURL", function($http, $scope, ServiceURL) {

    buildTable($http, $scope, ServiceURL.url[3]);

}]);
```

With this solution I have the possibility to have more than a table using only the same code and not copying - pasting my code.

Comment: this is not the way to accomplish this task, and **not** the way to use `ng-Init`. The `ng-init` is bound to the **element**, but your `$http.get` is in the **controller constructor**.  `this.initialize` can't be run until the controller has been constructed, and so, by the time the `initialize` function is called, the `$http.get` has already finished.

Comment: OK. How can I pass a parameter to my controller to select one or another url to execute in $http.get?

Comment: to be honest, without attaching this logic into a directive or only activating the `$http.get` after a user interaction, you won't achieve the result you want.  This isn't the way that angular expects to operate; the controller is in control over the view, not the other way around.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't simply place the url into the $http.get? You are still hard coding it.

Comment: I want to not hard coding the url, because If I want to reuse the same code, I have to copy-paste and change only this url. So, I'm looking for a way to not copy-paste and change this url.
I want to find a way to do so as not having to copy and paste the code

Comment: create a static variable at the top of your JavaScript file to assign the URL to, that you can change in that single location.  Don't try to use HTML to assign a JavaScript property.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! Finally, I h ave found a solution that you can see on my post

Answer (score 1):

In your case,

1. You are defining the  "self.type" inside the function "initialize()". As this is local to this function, You can't access this variable "self" in $http.get method.
2. As this you are defining this variable inside a function, it won't get initialized unless the function is invoked. So try to initialize the variable without the help of function (may be inside controller or service).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but If I initialize self.type outside the function initialize() it doesn't works, because the function initialize is called after the controller is constructed, and when the controller is constructed is when $http.get method is called, so in that moment self.type will be undefined.